# Msg 240, Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split a row when the ';' character appears. I have a list with projects, where one of the columns states which district the project belongs to. However some projects appears in multiple districts and is therefore written like "1;2;3" (District 1, 2 and 3). I want to create three rows form this and split on the ';'.

The error message says:

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "DataItem" of recursive query "tmp".

I tried the split_string, but discovered my server is 2014 and lacks compatibility.

```
WITH tmp(Oppdragsnr, Kommune, DataItem, Kommunenr) AS
(
    SELECT
        Oppdragsnr,
        Kommune,
        LEFT(Kommunenr, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';') - 1),
        STUFF(Kommunenr, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';'), '')
    FROM 
        oppdragene

    UNION all

    SELECT
        Oppdragsnr,
        Kommune,
        LEFT(Kommunenr, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';') - 1),
        STUFF(Kommunenr, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';'), '')
    FROM  
        tmp
    WHERE
        Kommunenr > ''
)
SELECT
    Oppdragsnr,
    Kommune,
    DataItem
FROM 
    tmp
ORDER BY 
    Oppdragsnr
```

I would like the output to be a new table with new rows for every project that appears in multiple districts.

Comment: It could be the length of the string returned by the `LEFT()` function, or even the different collation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably `CAST to INT` the DataItem column in the base and recursive part of the query, the following query should work for you

```
;WITH tmp(Oppdragsnr, Kommune, DataItem, Kommunenr) AS
(
    SELECT
        Oppdragsnr,
        Kommune,
        CAST(LEFT(Kommunenr, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';') - 1) AS INT),
        STUFF(Kommunenr, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';'), '')
    FROM 
        oppdragene

    UNION all

    SELECT
        Oppdragsnr,
        Kommune,
        CAST(LEFT(Kommunenr, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';') - 1)  AS INT),
        STUFF(Kommunenr, 1, CHARINDEX(';', Kommunenr + ';'), '')
    FROM  
        tmp
    WHERE
        Kommunenr > ''
)
SELECT
    Oppdragsnr,
    Kommune,
    DataItem
FROM 
    tmp
ORDER BY 
    Oppdragsnr
```